# How to force navbar-fixed-top to display after certain height

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'am calling a `template.php` page through `php` `include`. I have a bootstrap navbar in the `index.php` page and in the html page. While executing the `tepmlate.php` navbar displays over the `index.php` navbar.

I want to display `template.php` navbar below `index.php` navbar, i.e. I want the whole html file to display below `index.php` navbar, following is the html code:

template.php

```
<header id="navigation">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="banner">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header" data-nitspagelabel="1">....
```

index.php

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top editbar">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
```

CSS File:

```
.editbar {
  height: 44px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 600px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 rgba(22, 45, 61, 0.5);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 100;
  line-height: 48px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  transition: 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1) top;
 }
```

Is there any jquery function to fix this or any css change?

Comment: You need to add a `top` style to your `editbar` equal to the height of your `index.php` navbar. So if it is 50px in height, you need to add `top: 50px` to your `editbar`.

Comment: It has to be opposite.. I mean `editbar` should appear first, then below that `template.php` contents should appear.

Comment: So you can do the opposite. Editbar is `44px` in height, so you need to add `top: 44px` to your `template.php` navbar.

Comment: that ain't helping out..:( i tried it. Is there any jquery function for this?

Comment: Please see the answer I posted and its example. I think it will help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add a `top: 44px` to your `template.php` navbar.

[Simple Bootply Example](http://www.bootply.com/ZrEW6EjRqV)

```
.editbar {
  min-height: 44px; /* Override min-height of 50px */
  height: 44px;
}
.template-nav {
  top: 44px;
}

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top template-nav" role="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header" data-nitspagelabel="1">template.php</div>
  </div>
</div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top editbar">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">index.php</div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `margin-top: 50` as style to whichever bar you want to appear beneath the other. I have created a sample fiddle for demonstration.

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li> 
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top php-bar">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName2</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li> 
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
.php-bar {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/u95pnjsd/)**